# Maturity of Scala-LLVM?

Tags: scala, open-source, llvm, maturity

I'd like to know how mature the llvm-backend for Scala currently is and whether it is used in any open source project that I could have a look at.

Comment: if you're gonna vote to close, at least move it to "programmers"

Comment: while it is not pure *scala for llvm*, there is [JVM impementation](http://vmkit.llvm.org/) on top of llvm, so I guess you can have more running scala on VMKit than Geoff Reedy can give you atm.

Comment: The great thing about LLVM based solution would not having Garbage Collection. Glimpsed at Rust today, that seems to be their (only?) strength over Scala. And fast startup times, of course.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say (sadly) it's pretty immature. You need certain steps among them: a scala standard library without java dependencies and a runtime including garbage collection. Which are still TODO. From my incomplete view on the topic I would say there is more to be done than what's already done. Check this for more info: http://vimeo.com/28774096

Comment: Thanks for the video link! I could live without the standard library and even without seperate compilation, but no garbage collection? And then he talks about a bunch of unimportant things that need to be implemented...

Comment: Scala.js is kind of crafting a minimal-viable java.* set of APIs for non-JVM Scala. LLVM implementation could use the same. However, if LLVM also must run GC (does it?) I see little point in the whole operation.