# Scala compilation into machine code

Tags: scala, compilation, llvm

How to compile Scala into machine code ?

Is LLVM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) plausible ?

**Update**: Would such compilation make the code run any faster in the target machine ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're inquiring about the general feasibility of building a Scala->Machine code compiler, or looking for an existing product that does that?

Comment: " Update: Would such compilation make the code run faster for the target machine " - Not necessarily, the JVM's JIT compilers are pretty good nowadays (and can take advantage of what's happening at runtime, unlike an AOT compiler). Can you explain more about why you're thinking you might need to do this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371779/maturity-of-scala-llvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wind changed! happy to update new answer. :)

http://www.scala-native.org/

https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native

--

[outdated answer]

https://greedy.github.io/scala-llvm/

Geoff Reedy working on it.
HTH

Comment: Geoff Reedy *worked* on it (there is no progress for a loooong time and repository seems to be obsolete)

Comment: maybe, then, there is many samples to references. [ldc](https://github.com/ldc-developers/ldc), [julia](http://julialang.org/), [corvus](https://github.com/eudoxia0/corvus), [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), etc

Comment: huh? I don't get how are they relevant to *How to compile Scala into machine code?*